# Retry PowerShell commands if download fails

Tags: powershell

We use a PowerShell script that someone made to download new Windows Defender virus definitions from Microsoft to a network location.  There are four files that get downloaded.  The problem is, sometimes one or more of the downloads fail due a network or website issue.  So, I would like any download that fails to automatically retry until successful.  Below is what the relevant part of the script looks like.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
# Source Addresses - Defender for Windows 10, 8.1 ################################

$sourceAVx86 = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x86"
$sourceNISx86 = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187316&arch=x86&nri=true"
$sourceAVx64 = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x64"
$sourceNISx64 = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187316&arch=x64&nri=true"

# Web client #####################################################################

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

# x86 AV #########################################################################

$Dest = "$Destination\x86\" + 'mpam-fe.exe'
$wc.DownloadFile($sourceAVx86, $Dest) 

# x86 NIS ########################################################################

$Dest = "$Destination\x86\" + 'nis_full.exe'
$wc.DownloadFile($sourceNISx86, $Dest)

# x64 AV #########################################################################

$Dest = "$Destination\x64\" + 'mpam-fe.exe'
$wc.DownloadFile($sourceAVx64, $Dest)

# x64 NIS ########################################################################

$Dest = "$Destination\x64\" + 'nis_full.exe'
$wc.DownloadFile($sourceNISx64, $Dest)
```

Comment: Seems to me WSUS is more robust and pretty simple to implement.

Comment: You could try a recursive function in a `Try/Catch` block until it's successful.

Comment: Bill, we do use WSUS, but these specific downloads are used for updating the definitions during OSD imaging.

Comment: TheIncorrigible, after researching the issue I figured a Try/Catch would be involved, but just not sure how to implement it.  My PowerShell skills are...lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to test for the existence of the files at the destination.
If the file does not exist, then retry the download. I put in a variable to set how many times it should attempt the download before moving on.

```
$maxAttempts = 5 #set the maximum number of attempts in case the download will never succeed.

$sourceAVx86 = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x86"
$sourceNISx86 = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187316&arch=x86&nri=true"
$sourceAVx64 = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x64"
$sourceNISx64 = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187316&arch=x64&nri=true"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

#Define destination file paths:
$DestAVx86 = "$Destination\x86\" + 'mpam-fe.exe'
$DestNISx86 = "$Destination\x86\" + 'nis_full.exe'
$DestAVx64 = "$Destination\x64\" + 'mpam-fe.exe'
$DestNISx64 = "$Destination\x64\" + 'nis_full.exe'

#Delete old versions of the files if they exist
if (Test-Path $DestAVx86) {
    Remove-Item $DestAVx86
}
if (Test-Path $DestNISx86) {
    Remove-Item $DestNISx86
}
if (Test-Path $DestAVx64) {
    Remove-Item $DestAVx64
}
if (Test-Path $DestNISx64) {
    Remove-Item $DestNISx64
}

$attemptCount = 0
Do {
    $attemptCount++
    $wc.DownloadFile($sourceAVx86, $Dest)
} while (((Test-Path $DestAVx86) -eq $false) -and ($attemptCount -le $maxAttempts))

$attemptCount = 0
Do {
    $attemptCount++
    $wc.DownloadFile($sourceNISx86, $Dest) 
} while (((Test-Path $DestNISx86) -eq $false) -and ($attemptCount -le $maxAttempts))

$attemptCount = 0
Do {
    $attemptCount++
    $wc.DownloadFile($sourceAVx64, $Dest) 
} while (((Test-Path $DestAVx64) -eq $false) -and ($attemptCount -le $maxAttempts))

$attemptCount = 0
Do {
    $attemptCount++
    $wc.DownloadFile($sourceNISx64, $Dest) 
} while (((Test-Path $DestNISx64) -eq $false) -and ($attemptCount -le $maxAttempts))
```

Comment: Tried that.  It deleted the old files but did not download the new ones.

Comment: Check that the $Destination variable is set.  I didn't see it in your script and I didn't assign it any value in mine.

Comment: It's in there, I just didn't show it.  It's tough to troubleshoot because someone else is running it from the SCCM server because I don't have access to it.  Anything else you can think of?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to change the $Dest in the download commands to the new $DestAVx86, etc.  It works now!  Thank you so much.

Comment: I thought of one other question about this script.  The next command (not shown) after the above commands updates the package on the distribution points. Will the downloads finish before it starts that? Below is the code.  <br/>$SiteCode = $(Get-WMIObject -ComputerName “$ENV:COMPUTERNAME” -Namespace “root\SMS” -Class “SMS_ProviderLocation”).SiteCode
$pkg = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName “$ENV:COMPUTERNAME” -Namespace "Root\SMS\Site_$SiteCode" -Class SMS_Package -Filter "PackageID='$PackageID'"
$pkg.RefreshPkgSource()

Comment: Powershell commands execute one at a time so the downloads will finish before continuing.